# algoliasearchHelper hierarchical facets

Tags: algolia

I am trying to implement a hierarchical category menu with [Algolia's searchHelper.js](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-helper-js), but the category content is not showing.

https://jsfiddle.net/t0tue5rk/1/

Sample Algolia record:

```
objectID: 41
title: "Canon 40D With Lens"
hierarchicalCategories: {
"lvl0" : "Video Juegos y Consolas",
"lvl1" : "Video Juegos y Consolas > PS3",
"lvl2" : "Video Juegos y Consolas > PS3 > Juegos"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hierarchical facets are different from the conjunctive and disjunctive facets in that they are based on a tree. The problem in your example is that you reuse the same kind of template for this different structure. You can find more information about the manipulation of hierarchical facets on the main [documentation of the Algolia JS Helper](https://community.algolia.com/algoliasearch-helper-js/reference.html#hierarchical-facets).

I also [fixed your sample](https://jsfiddle.net/x7drus01/7/) on jsFiddle. Here are the parts that I changed:

- Handling the hierarchical facets when receiving data (l.128):

  ```
  else if(facetName === 'categories') {
    facetContent = {
      facet: facetName,
      title: FACETS_LABELS[facetName],
      values: content.getFacetValues(facetName, {sortBy: ['isRefined:desc', 'count:desc']})
    };
    facetsHtml += hierarchicalFacetTemplate.render(
      facetContent,
      {sub: hierarchicalFacetTemplateSource});
  }
  ```

  For the sake of simplicity, I hardcoded the name of the attribute.
- Create two templates, one for the container and one for the recursively going through the tree of values. (html: l.117-138)

  ```
  <script type="text/template" id="hierarchical-facet-header-template">
    <div class="facet facet-hierarchical">
      <h5>{{ title }}</h5>
      {{#values}}
        {{>sub}}
      {{/values}}
    </div>
  </script>

  <!-- Hierarchical Facet template -->
  <script type="text/template" id="hierarchical-facet-template">
      <ul>
        {{#data}}
        <li>
          <a href="" class="facet-link toggle-refine facet-hierarchical {{#isRefined}}facet-refined{{/isRefined}}" data-facet="{{ facet }}" data-value="{{ path }}">
            {{ name }}<span class="facet-count">{{ count }}</span>
          </a>
        {{>sub}}
        </li>
      {{/data}}
    </ul>
  </script>
  ```
- Import those new templates to the JS. (js: l.44-46)

  ```
  var hierarchicalFacetHeaderTemplateSource = $('#hierarchical-facet-header-template').text();
  var hierarchicalFacetTemplateSource = $('#hierarchical-facet-template').text();
  var hierarchicalFacetTemplate = Hogan.compile(hierarchicalFacetHeaderTemplateSource);
  ```